# Consent dialog for using capabilities on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a Windows phone application which uses Network and Location capabilities.

All apps using any kind of these capabilities or others, will first display a consent dialog ("this app will use microphone, do you allow this?").

This dialog appears on first use by default on the Windows Runtime apps. But what about the apps for Windows Phone (Universal app, still using WinRT)?

Should I display a dialog for the first time usage of the capability or the OS handles this automatically? In Debug mode, nothing ever appears. I've also tested the app in Release Mode, and still nothing. So, do we have to manually handle this or the OS will handle a display of such dialog when the package is to be installed and used on other devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trust that the operating system will do the right thing for user consent when you declare a capability such as location. On Windows, as you've seen, this consent prompt happens on first run. The model for Windows Phone is to ask for consent at installation time. Either way, the system will take care of the prompting for you--you need not implement your own prompt.

Indeed, if you think it through more carefully, what would you do with the accept/decline answer from such a custom prompt? The whole purpose of the consent prompt is to broker access to sensitive WinRT APIs, which means those APIs will fail unless consent has been granted. Apps can't be given the power to make that decision on their own, because it would defeat the whole purpose of consent. Thus even if you obtained accept/decline yourself, there's nothing you could do with that value; there's no API to set permissions programmatically, as only the user can do that through Settings.

The consent prompts are just a way to initialize those permission settings at the appropriate time, and again, you can trust the system will do the right thing.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. Now that you've put it into words, if I'm thinking better, creating the prompt manually does seem weird. Basically, in my app if the user doesn't accept the location consent, he or she can't really use it, they're redirected to a menu page. Thanks once again for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, the pattern here is that if you use an API for which consent has not been given, it will fail with access denied. That's your signal to alert the user about permissions, or direct them elsewhere.

Comment: So, if I'm installing this app from Store but I decline the location permission, will the installation continue or will it be halted? And then the app might crash when I'll want to get the user location but the app doesn't have the permission?

Comment: I don't know the phone model exactly. If it installs without the consent, then the applicable APIs will fail until the user grants permission; you need to catch such errors anyway of course. If the app doesn't install when the user doesn't grant consent, then there's nothing more you need to do.

Comment: On Windows Phone you cannot install the app if you don't accept the Store-provided prompt. That said, you are still required to provide your own in-app settings to enable / disable location services for Windows Phone apps (for Windows apps, this is in the Charms bar) - see [section 10.5.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn764944). Yes this is on the "honour system" once installed.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone universal apps uses WinRT APIs as well, and same general guidelines described below applies to Windows Phone as well. However, there are differences in settings charm . The best way for you to test is publish the windows phone app as beta, then see if there is a consent prompt.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh768223.aspx

Comment: If I am not mistaken the official Microsoft app for Facebook displays such dialogs when the app is to be installed from the  Store. I wonder if this is handled automatically by the OS or not...

Comment: The BETA idea is nice though, I thought of perhaps having something like that and then a stabilization update.

Comment: Here is the information about beta testing your app http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215598(v=vs.105).aspx